# Firebase doesn't connect with my android application

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm trying to setup firebase on my android application when I install my app on emulator or real device firebase not recognize my installation and stick on forth step of installation of firebase (Run your app to verify installation)
I skip that but on install number or notification reciver count will not show my app.
funny thing is I implemented in a test project and it work.

this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    applicationId "netherland.com.app.vanlaartsoapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-alpha01'
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for assistance troubleshooting your project.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure from adding google.json file to your project